# Liquibase migration with H2 and Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I use Spring boot and H2 DB. I want to include Liquibase in my app. I have have multiple modules app. There are entity, dao, service, controller, etc modules. I created Liquibase files in Dao module.
This is application.property:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/migration/master.xml
```

This is liquibase.property:

```
classpath=
changeLogFile=db/migration/master.xml
url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
username=sa
password=password
driver=org.h2.Driver
```

And here is master.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <include file="v-1-0-0/changelog-project-v-1.0.0-cumulative.xml"/>
    <include file="v-1-0-1/changelog-project-v-1.0.1-cumulative.xml"/>
    
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And I have an error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: The file v-1-0-0/changelog-project-v-1.0.0-cumulative.xml was not found in
    - Spring resources
```

But, I think that I don't need to specify files form master.xml in properties.
Please, help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMmWQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the path to the `changelog-project-v-1.0.0-cumulative.xml` is incorrect. Try using `relativeToChangelogFile="true"`

In `master.xml` put the following:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <include file="v-1-0-0/changelog-project-v-1.0.0-cumulative.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="v-1-0-1/changelog-project-v-1.0.1-cumulative.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    
</databaseChangeLog>
```